# What determine number of cpu core usage of filter select=gt(scene,0.1)?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've notice that when using filter gt(scene,0.1), for example:

`ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.mkv -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.1)',showinfo" -f null -`

Depends on the video, number of cpu cores usage varies extremely (sometimes it 3 cores usage - other time 12 cores usage in different video).

Would like to ask what determine that logic ?

I try to read ffmpeg source code but not familiar with it, a general explanation would be enough, but much appreciate if you point out the line/directory determine that logic in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.

(Also not asking how to reduce cpu usage, interested in the logic determine that).

Answer (score 0):

In source code there is no mention of multi threading on filter, keyword for searching in source code: `get_scene_score`, `scene_sad`.

Further searching suggest that this is due to video decoding and not related to filter (filter always use 1 cpu core - thus could use `-threads 1` to limit cpu usage, position of params `-threads` also matter).